# sharding collection that has two ore more unique indices in mongodb 2.2

Tags: mongodb

I am newbie and exploring mongdodb. after reading  http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/, i understood that sharding collection with multiple unique indices is not possible.

A-  If this is true, does the error message below describe the actual problem?

```
mongos> db.twouniques.ensureIndex( { unique1: 1}, {unique: true} );
mongos> db.twouniques.ensureIndex( { unique2: 1}, {unique: true} );
mongos> db.runCommand( { shardCollection : "testdb.twouniques", key: {unique1:1,unique2:1} })
```

> {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "can't shard collection 'testdb.twouniques' with unique index on { unique1: 1.0 } and proposed shard key { unique1: 1.0, unique2: 1.0 }. Uniqueness can't be maintained unless shard key is a prefix"}

B- using proxy collection and doing two inserts could be very expensive, is there any other  option(s)?, given that  sharding is required, and creating one field that combines the two fields, which have unique indices, is not possible(per application dev.)?

Comment: A long time but any resolution on this?